# TFS 2010 Build Definitions are not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have been facing this issue quite since a long time, and this is repetitive.

Application : Team Foundation Server 2010

What is the Issue: Users report that the build definitions are not visible.

Who observe the issue: Members that are specific to a project report the issue. However, the Project administrators(Default Collections) can access and queue builds without issues.

What is done as a workaround: We restart the TFS server, and reapply account from the Application Tier, after which the builds are visible to respective project Contributors.

Can some one let me know, what would be the issue, root cause, how to fix it?

Please add for any queries.